# Не могу загрузить файлы на сервер больше 4мб

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

При загрузке фалов больше 4мб, страница грузится в течении 60 сек. Потом белый экран. Вроде бы в настройках nginx и php всё, что можно было изменил. Но файлы всё равно не грузятся

Comment: Может, у вас ошибка в php-коде, который обрабатывает файл?

Comment: В первую очередь, предоставьте больше деталей, что у вас за php движок (например, в Wordpress есть свой лимит), а также какие настройки вы меняли

Comment: Ошибки в php точно нет, мелкие файлы загружаются. Движок на yii2 написан. Проблема где-то в настройках сервака т.к. на openserver всё норм отрабатывает.
nginx:
client_max_body_size 100M;
client_body_timeout 300;
client_header_timeout 300;

php:
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
memory_limit = 200M
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

точно в php.ini все пучком? проверьте... (и до кучи ту ли инишку использует php)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M

max_execution_time = 600
; also, higher if you must - sets the maximum time in seconds
```